# Ember source code hosting URL for handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I know that http://builds.emberjs.com/ has

- [Ember Latest Stable](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest-stable.js)
- [Ember Data Latest](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js)

But where can I find the latest compatible handlebars source URL?

http://emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/getting-started/handlebars.js is version 2 but the latest Ember requires version 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You can find the latest compatible `handlebars.js` directly here:

http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js

So this leaves you with:

- http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js

which should work nicely together.

Hope it helps.

Edit: note that handlebars must be included first.

Comment: So they don't have a "handlebars-latest" URL?

Comment: I still get an error!
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js". index.html:12
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js". index.html:12
Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0. Include a SCRIPT tag in the HTML HEAD linking to the Handlebars file before you link to Ember. ember-latest.js:361
(anonymous function) ember-latest.js:361
Ember.assert ember-latest.js:52
slice ember-latest.js:19643 ...

Comment: @c4p no, I don't know, but they should, so everything would be listed in one place

Comment: @HaoQiLi see here a working jsbin with the versions mentioned above: http://jsbin.com/imurul/2/edit and as for the mime type error it's not affecting the functionality