# Is there an ember-model source code hosting URL?

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking for an online url for the source of [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model), because http://builds.emberjs.com/ doesn't have it and https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/tree/master/packages/ember-model/lib has too many javascript files. I just want one to be included in html.

Comment: If I could ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437690/ember-source-code-hosting-url-for-handlebars, how is this question off-topic?  Please help me and help others with the same question. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there is no ember-model hosting URL, but agreed it would be a good thing. Maybe if you ask nicely here: https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/issues

Comment: @MikeGrassotti if there is no hosting URL how are people using ember-model? Do they download and include all [these files](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/tree/master/packages/ember-model/lib) one by one in their html?

Comment: Can't speak for others but what I do is clone the repo and run the build, then include `ember-model.js`. See https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model#building-ember-model